# Is there a Smart Meter simulator which generates data

Tags: simulation

I am working on a Smart Grid project and we want a real-time smart meter data. Because of the difficulty of getting this real-time data we want kind of software simulator that generates this data? Is there any helpful application like this?

Comment: Do you have a specific model of smart meter in mind you would like to simulate? I expect the manufacturer of the meter could provide more help.

Comment: If you know what the smart meter sends you can write a simulator yourself

Comment: Questions seeking to find / buy things are not on topic.  Realistically, you'll probably want to code this up yourself, as the hard part is not the simulation, but deciding what conditions to simulate.  Alternatively, you should perhaps go shopping for a collection of some *actual* data of past usage.

Comment: Buy a smart meter and see what it sends - if it should work with all the manufacturers get multiple. Yes there are standards, but often enough there are quirks in the implementation of each device...

Comment: I don't have any specific model I just want to simulate a smart meter of a house for example, so it sends the data of washing machine, electric vehicle, TV, air conditioner, etc. to the smart grid. Because our project needs to get real-time data to work. In addition, I want to simulate PhotoVolatic and Trubine, it is like smart grid working in real-time receiving and send data.